# Enable GZIP correctly

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, optimization, gzip

I am not able to enable GZIP on my website. It is hosted on nodejs server.

It shows gzip enabled when testing locally, but when deployed on the server I don't see response header in dev tools. Following is the code:

```
var compression = require('compression')
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);

app.use(compression(9));
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.setHeader('Content-Encoding', 'gzip')
});
```

If I make following changes, I can see gzip enabled and response header coming from server as well, but many of my content fails to load with error like `"http://127.0.0.1:3000/lib/jquery-ui.js net::ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED"`

```
var compression = require('compression')
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);

app.use(compression(9));
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader('Content-Encoding', 'gzip, deflate');
return next();
});
```

**Update**
curl command from terminal shows gzip enabled but on browser, the response header is not coming

Curl->

```
curl -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip" -I https://<MY_WEB_URL>
```

Output->

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Mon, 22 May 2017 08:50:52 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Powered-By: Express
ETag: W/"15457-1492724210000"
Cache-Control: public, max-age=0
Last-Modified: Thu, 20 Apr 2017 21:36:50 GMT
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

**Developer tool shows some files as gzipped and some not.**
[image]

**YSlow shows gzip not enabled**
[image]

**IS GZIP ENABLED???**